# user's last login date and time facebook graph explorer

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have search a lot on this site and google to get the last login date and time of a particular facebook user from user id using the graph explorer. However, could not find a relevant article.

I have 20+ employees working in my office and I do not want them to access facebook during shift timings. I have their user ids with me. Is it possible to check when did they last login/logout or performed any activity on facebook using their FB UIDs using a php/mysql or any other way or just by using the graph explorer?

I read some articles that had fql options but i could not try those as fql is depreciated. Any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you meant to use a Graph or Graphic ?

Using a table to log-in when your users accessed Facebook will be simpler.

You'll have to apply a filter to remove results outside the *shift timings*.

Once you are done with it, creating a bar graphic will be an easy solution.

If you want to use the Graph API, you need to make sure that your employees log-on onto your application and give their consent.

You should check : https://developers.facebook.com/policy before trying anything.

> Only use our SDKs to develop and distribute apps for use with the
>   Facebook Platform. You may also distribute any code libraries or
>   sample source code included in the SDKs for inclusion in such apps.

Use simple network functions like logs to collect data.

Enabling a Firewall is better than *making* Facebook accessible in those shift hours.

---

If you meant Graph API, it's a *social graph explorer*. It's meant to show all the relations between the users. I am not sure how far it deviates from a *graph*, neither if it has some visualization capabilities.

---

Using the Graph API to monitor your workers might be a grave legal infringement. There are many laws protecting privacy at work. The Graph API can give all kind of information. I would **not** suggest to use any kind of solution that gives access to some sensitive data...

Logging all the Connections going to FB would be the only choice.

Comment: I meant Graph.. as in Graph Explorer. I do not want to deploy a firewall. I thought there must be some solution to find last login, logout or any activity on facebook using the user id. In this way I can randomly run the code and check if anyone is using facebook

Comment: I have seen some websites that just take the page name and display insights of that page like shares, likes, comments etc. If that is possible, I thought getting a small metric of a user using his user id is also possible but I could not find any relevant article :(